# Find all files that contain all words/lines in another file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm going to go right out and say this is a homework question, but I feel like I've exhausted my search online for anything relating to how to do this problem or I am just not wording it correctly for Google/Stackoverflow.

The question starts out like this: File ***words*** contains a list of words. Each word is on a seperate line. Files ***story1, story2, ..., story100*** are short stories.

It's a multi-part question, but the very last part is stumping me: Find out story files that contain all words that are in file ***words.***

There was a question before it that's similar: Find out story files (print file names) that contain at least one word from file ***words***.

This one I solved by using grep:

```
grep -l -f words story*
```

I was under the impression that I would also have to use grep for the last problem, but I can't seem to find an option for grep or anything that would return only those files that match everything that is in a pattern file. It appears I may have to do this with a shell script, but unsure of where to start or if I even need grep for this. Any pointers on how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

These are the correct answers from the solution the instructor gave us.

**Question before main question:** `grep -l -f words story*`

**Main question:**

```
for story in `ls story*`
do
    (( match = 0 ))

    for word in `cat words`
    do
        if [ `grep -l $word $story` ]
        then
            (( match++ ))
        else
            break
        fi
    done

    if [ $match -eq `wc -w < words` ]
    then
        echo $story
    fi
done
```

Thanks everyone for their thoughtful input and answers and sorry I'm a little late on getting this out there.

Comment: Can't think of a way to do it with just `grep` without using `eval/evil`. But you could loop over the files and read each one line by line, then if you found a line which isn't present don't print anything, otherwise print the file name after the loop is done. Also, just a suggestion, but you may want to look into brace expansion `{1..#}`, since while your solution to the other question technically covers `story1..100`, it could also catch errant files.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, BroSlow, I'll try that! And hah, I didn't catch that, thanks for pointing that out also! I was so happy to actually get a solution with that question that kinda slipped my mind.

Comment: `grep -l -f words story*` does not do what you seem to think. It tells grep to look for text in `story*` that matches the regular expressions contained in `words`. The most obvious problem that would cause you is that if `words` contains the word `the` one of the story files contains the word `then`, then grep will report that the RE `the` WAS found in that file since `the` matches the start of `then`. You need to use a tool that provides word boundaries at least, e.g. GNU awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# wcheck: finds story* files that contain all words in words file

# for each file named story... (in this directory)
for file in story*
do
    stGood=0  # story is intialized as containing words or true

    ## for each word in the words file
    for word in $(cat words) ; do

        ## if test using grep exit status for existance of word
        if ! grep -q -F $word $file
        then
            stGood=1 #if word is not found story is set to false
            break
        fi   
    done
    ## if story is still true then filename is printed
    if [ $stGood == 0 ]
        then
        echo $file
    fi
done
exit
```

Answer (score 1):

The brute force method probably isn't the fastest way to do this, but as long as you don't have 100,000+ words and stories, it's fine. Basically, you will just test that each file contains each word using grep, one at a time. If a grep fails to find the word in story, move on to the next story. If all words are found in story, add story to a goodstories array. At the end, just print all goodstories:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a words        # array containing all words
declare -a goodstories  # array contianing stories with all words

words=( `< /path/to/words` )    # fill words array

## for each stories file (assumed they exist in dir of their own)
for s in `find /path/to/stories/base/dir -type f` ; do

    wfound=0                    # all words found flag initialized to 'true'

    ## for each word in words
    for w in ${words[@]}; do

        ## test that word is in story, if not set wfound=1 break
        grep -q $w $s &>/dev/null || {

            wfound=1
            break

        }

    done

    ## if grep found all words, add story to goodstories array
    test "$wfound" -eq 0 && goodstories+=( $s )

done

## output your list of goodstories

if test "${#goodstories[@]}" -gt 0 ; then

    echo -e "\nStories that contained all words:\n"
    for s in ${goodstories[@]}; do

        echo "  $s"

    done

else

    echo "No stories contained all words"

fi

exit 0
```

NOTE: I didn't create a words or stories file, so if you find a typo, etc.. consider the code as pseudo code. However, it wasn't just slapped together either...

Comment: If `the` is in `words` and `there` is in a `story` file then that grep command will incorrectly report that the word `the` is present in that file. You need the `-w` arg for grep (may be GNU ]only?). General advice: Dont use deprecated ticks to excute commands, use `$(..)` instead. Don't use a for loop on the output of find, use `find ... | while IFS= read -r s` instead. Use `(( var == 0 ))` for arithmetic ops, not `test $var == 0`. No need for `exit 0` at the end that's the default.

Comment: Ed, I appreciate the tips, but as for the backticks, what reference do you rely on to conclude they are deprecated? I have traditionally used `$()`, but then others complain about portability. I see the remainder of the advise in the same light. `find | while` -- I've have seen time and time again arguments for eliminating pipes, thus the `for`. `test` blah is just for portability as well. Yes, `exit 0` is the default, but it is akin to dotting `i's` and crossing `t's`. With the myriad of conflicting "do it this ways" it would be nice if there was an agreed upon std.

Comment: Maybe deprecated is too strong a word but backticks are in every way inferior and are only necessary in the very oldest non-POSIX-compatible shells (see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) so using them for portability is not useful. `find | while` is the simple way to deal with file names that contain whitespaces, if you dont want a pipe there are alternatives but `for file in $(find...)` is not an option. `test "$var" -eq 0` is less readable than `(( var == 0 ))` and I suspect has more caveats based on the value of `var`. `exit 0` you can add if you like, but it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Ok, I can use `while IFS='as needed' -r s; do ..stuff..; done <<< $(find stuff)` and eliminate the pipe; but I do not see any contraindication to `for file in $(find stuff); do..` either. I may be missing something I'm just ignorant of (at present), but what is wrong with `for .. in $(find ..)`? You can predicate it upon the same `IFS=$'stuff'`; just as with file, so word-splitting isn't the issue. What causes you to say it isn't an option?

Comment: Sorry, it's been years since I saw the rationale and scenarios discussed, if you post a question in the comp.unix.shell newsgroup I'm sure you'll get chapter and verse.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for the discussion and tips, it benefits us all (me especially).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your words file contains no RE metacharacters with GNU awk for `\<...\>` work boundaries:

To list files containing one word:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { words["\\<" $0 "\\>"]; next }
{
    for (word in words) {
        if ($0 ~ word) {
            print FILENAME
            next
        }
    }
}
' words story*
```

To list files containing all words (GNU awk for additionally ENDFILE, delete(array) and length(array)):

```
awk '
NR==FNR { words["\\<" $0 "\\>"]; next }
{
    for (word in words) {
        if ($0 ~ word) {
            found[word]
        }
    }
}
ENDFILE {
    if ( length(found) == length(words) ) {
        print FILENAME
    }
    delete found
}
' words story*
```

Comment: Won't the second one fail as missing will always be set to 1 due to every other word not matching the line. Wouldn't it be better to do if `($0 ~ word){found =1}` ?

Comment: Ah, good point, that second one as written would require every word to match on every line of the story file, not just once in the file. Your proposal wouldn't work as it would set found for any word being found while we need it set when all words have been found. I just updated my answer. I wonder if that's what the downvote was for?

Comment: I left the comment too long and couldn't edit it. I meant set a flag like `found` and then you could increment. If it matched the number of words then print it out. Pretty similar to what you have changed it to :)

Comment: Incrementing one variable wouldn't have workd as the same word could appear multiple times. You need to do SOMETHING with an array for this one, either add to one, or delete from words or...

Comment: Oh yeah,didn't think it through properly.Mine would have only worked if there was one occurence of the word.

Answer (score 0):

```
for EachFile in story*
 do
    sed 's/  */\
/g' ${EachFile} | sort -u > /tmp/StoryInList
    if [ $( fgrep -w -c -v -f /tmp/StoryInList words ) -eq 0 ]
     then
       echo ${EachFile}
     fi
 done
rm /tmp/StoryInList
```

a bit of code in batch but do the job even if several thousand of words using the grep strength

Comment: Words aren't always separated by blank chars (see how @SylvainLeroux does it) and will match `the` against `there` (see my other comments).

Comment: ohh, very good comment, i miss it, adapt the reply adding option `-w` for a word compare only in (f)grep.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of *unique* words to search, and for each story the list of *unique* words it contains, the problem is easier to solve using `fgrep -c`:

```
# remove duplicates words in a file
# place them one per line
function buildWordList() {
    sed -e 's/[^[:alpha:]][^[:alpha:]]*/'$"\n"'/g' "$1" |
           tr [:upper:] [:lower:] | sort -u | sed '/^$/d'
    #      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    #      Works for English. 
}

TMP=$(mktemp -d)
trap "rm -rf $TMP" EXIT

buildWordList word | sed /.*/^@$/ > $TMP/Words
#                        ^^^^^^^^
#                     force whole word matching (as we have 1 word/line)
#                     `grep -w` might have been instead below. But I don't
#                     know if this is GNU-specific though
count=$(wc -l < $TMP/Words)

for file in story*
 do
    # build a list of unique words in the story, one per line
    buildWordList "${file}" > $TMP/FileWords
    if [ $( grep -c -f $TMP/Words $TMP/FileWords ) -eq $count ]
     then
       echo "${file}"
     fi
 done
```

Comment: WHat does the `$` do at the start of your sed command (`sed -e $'<script>'`)? Note that this will match `the` with `there`, see my other comments in this thread. You need to add a trap to remove the tmp files you're creating.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you Ed for pointing out the various errors on "our" answers ! I fixed the extra `$` at the start of the `sed` command, used `mktemp` to create a temporary dir, and most important of all, _probably_ have fixed the the issue concerning "matching prefixes" (`the` vs `there`). I said _probably_ as I am not able to test it for now...